# getting NullPointer Exception in Handling AutoSuggestion in Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium

I am Automating add to card process of **"http://www.fnp.com/the-sweet-surprises-genpr-143431-e.html"** website. I am writing a code Using **TestNG POM** Structure . I got Stuck in task where I am getting **NullPointer Exception** in Handling Autosuggestion. Below is my POM Class

```
public class productPage_POM {
    public WebDriver driver;

    @FindBy(id="tagsf2")
    private WebElement city_txtbox;

public productPage_POM(WebDriver driver)
    {
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    }

    public void sel_adr()
    {
        city_txtbox.sendKeys("gan");     // on this line i am gettign nullpointer Exception 

        String xp = "//a[starts-with(text(),'gan')]";
        List<WebElement> allList = driver.findElements(By.xpath(xp));
        int count = allList.size();
        System.out.println(count);
        for (int i = 0; i < count ; i++) 
        {
            String name = allList.get(i).getText();
            System.out.println(name);
            if(name.contains("Gandhinagar"))
            {
                allList.get(i).click();
                break;
            }
        }
```

Below is HTML structure

```
<div class="pro_detail">
<div id="changeImage" class="pro_detail_image">
<div class="pro_detail_title">
<div class="pro_detail_size">
<div class="pro_detail_form">
<input id="cityIdHidden" type="hidden" value="CITY-1219">
<input id="hasShippingOption" type="hidden" value="">
<input id="cityIdHidden1" type="hidden" value="">
<input id="liCount" type="hidden" value="1">
<div id="hiddenField">
<div class="pro_detail_form_inn">
<label>1. Where do you want to deliver this?</label>
<input id="tagsf2" class="inp_pro_detail2 election ui-autocomplete-input" type="text" value="Enter City" onchange="showAddtocart();" onblur="WatermarkOnblur('Enter City','tagsf2');shippingOption();" onfocus="WatermarkOnfocus('Enter City','tagsf2')" autocomplete="off">
<span class="ui-helper-hidden-accessible" role="status" aria-live="polite">CITY-1219</span>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div id="cityNotAvailable" class="error_message hide" style="display: none;">
</div>
<div class="textbox">
</div>
<div class="pro_detail_form">
<div id="divDeliveryText" class="pro_detail_form" style="display:none;">
<div id="valentineCatalougueText" class="pro_detail_form" style="display:block;">
<div class="pro_detail_form">
```

Comment: Make sure your locator 'city_txtbox' is initialized, In code I am unable to find it's xpath.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The below code will work:**

```
    String xp = "//ul/li/a[@class='ui-corner-all']";
    List<WebElement> allList = driver.findElements(By.xpath(xp));
    int count = allList.size();
    System.out.println(count);
    for (int i = 0; i < count ; i++) 
    {
        String name = allList.get(i).getText();
        System.out.println(name);
        if(name.contains("Gandhinagar"))
        {
            allList.get(i).click();
            break;
        }

}
```

Comment: mention not @RahilKumar:)

Comment: can u look one more part. just click on link
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34945125/unable-to-select-from-ui-li-elements-in-selenium-java?noredirect=1#comment57622022_34945125)

Answer (score 0):

I think autocomplete creates a list. So it should be

```
String xp = "//li[starts-with(text(),'gan')]";
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,40 );
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementsLocated(By.xpath(xp)));
```

I think it takes time for the autocomplete to load, but there should be some delay after which you should try to find the elements. Try ***WebDriverWait*** and let me know.

Comment: try using Wait as above.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize your `WebElement` before click or sendkeys.

```
WebElement webelement = getDriver().findElement(By.id("tagsf2"));
webelement.sendKeys("gan");
```

Remaining logic seems correct. Just make sure your suggetion field's xpath is correct.