# unable to select from ui li elements in selenium java

Tags: java, html, selenium

I am Automating add to card process of "http://www.fnp.com/the-sweet-surprises-genpr-143431-e.html" website. I am writing a code Using TestNG  Structure . I got Stuck in task where I got stuck in "Shipping Option" Box. 
I am getting null value in console. 
Below is my testNG Program

```
    package script;

    import java.util.Iterator;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
    import org.junit.Test;
    import org.openqa.selenium.By;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
    import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
    import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;

    import pom.Homepage_POM;

    public class mis {
            public static WebDriver driver;
        public static void main(String a[])
        {
            driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                  driver.get("http://www.fnp.com/the-sweet-surprises-genpr-143431-e.html");

 driver.findElement(By.id("tagsf2")).sendKeys("Gandhinagar");
     String xp = "//ul/li/a[@class='ui-corner-all']";
                    List<WebElement> allList = driver.findElements(By.xpath(xp));
                    int count = allList.size();
                                    for (int i = 0; i < count ; i++) 
                    {
                        String name = allList.get(i).getText();
                        //System.out.println(name);
                        if(name.contains("Gandhinagar"))
                        {
                            allList.get(i).click();
                            break;
                        }

                } 
                    List<WebElement> allElements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@id='ddShipingModep1_container']/ul/li")); 
            for (int i = 0; i < allElements.size() ; i++) 
                        {
                                String name2 = allElements.get(i).getText();
                            System.out.println(name2);
                             if(name2.contains("Standard Delivery [  Rs. 0 ]"))
                                {
                                    allElements.get(i).click();
                                    break;
                                }
```

Below is HTML code

```
<div class="textbox">
<div id="plsenter" style="display:none">Only standard delivery available for Mother's Day</div>
<div id="anand" class="pro_detail_form_inn flot-right">
<label>2. Shipping option</label>
<input id="ddShipingModep1_input" class="selectbox" type="text" autocomplete="off" readonly="readonly"/>
<div id="ddShipingModep1_container" class="selectbox-wrapper" style="display: none; width: 274px;">
<ul>
<li id="ddShipingModep1_input_option1" class="">Select Shipping Mode</li>
<li id="ddShipingModep1_input_SHMD-10" class="">Standard Delivery [  Rs. 0 ]</li>
<li id="ddShipingModep1_input_SHMD-768" class="selected">Fix Time Delivery [  Rs. 200 ]</li>
<li id="ddShipingModep1_input_SHMD-781">Midnight Delivery [  Rs. 250 ]</li>
</ul>
</div>
<select id="ddShipingModep1" class="inp_pop_quick_view" onchange="changeShipmentTime()" name="Items" style="display: none;">
<input id="valentineDisabled" type="hidden" value="false"/>
<input id="isValentinerose" type="hidden" value="false"/>
</div>
```

Comment: paste your console log

Comment: @niharika_neo console is looking Empty. You can directly run this code

Answer (score 1):

```
WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();

driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.get("http://www.fnp.com/the-sweet-surprises-genpr-143431-e.html");
driver.findElement(By.id("tagsf2")).sendKeys("Gandhinagar");
```

/*The below three line code is to select the option "Gandhinagar " from the drop down box for City name */

```
WebElement selectShippingModeInput =    driver.findElement(By.id("ddShipingModep1_input"));
selectShippingModeInput.click();     
selectShippingModeInput =    driver.findElement(By.id("ddShipingModep1_input"));
selectShippingModeInput.click();
```

/* The below code
 fetches all the options from the drop down box for "Shipping option"*/

```
List<WebElement>     options=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@id='ddShipingModep1_container']/ul/li"));
for(WebElement option:options){
```

/*The below code fetches the text of the drop down items */

```
String name=option.getText();
```

/*The below two line code is to focus on the select box*/

```
   selectShippingModeInput = driver.findElement(By.id("ddShipingModep1_input"));     
   selectShippingModeInput.click();
```

/*The drop down item "Standard Delivery [Rs. 0] is selected from the drop down box */

```
if(name.equals("Standard Delivery [ Rs. 0 ]")){
               selectShippingModeInput.click();
               option.click();
               break;

                                            }
                       }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! It could be helpful to add some explanation how your code solves the question.

Answer (score 0):

You have to click the `<input id="ddShipingModep1_input"` twice, then the options will be displayed. See code below:

```
...
WebElement selectShippingModeInput = driver.findElement(By.id("ddShipingModep1_input"));
selectShippingModeInput.click();        
selectShippingModeInput = driver.findElement(By.id("ddShipingModep1_input"));
selectShippingModeInput.click();
try {
    Thread.sleep(1000);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}

List<WebElement> allElements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@id='ddShipingModep1_container']/ul/li"));
...
```